# Ng-repeat - What is the right syntax to send the user to its dynamic id?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, laravel-5.3

So, in my object index I'm working inside a `ng-repeat`.

Now, when I click on an object, it should go to its matching `id`.

How would I do this with Angular?

I got something like this now:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dossier in dossiers">
    <td>
        <a href="@{{ url('/dossiers/' . dossier.id) }}">@{{dossier.license_plate}}</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try ngHref directive

```
<tr ng-repeat="dossier in dossiers">
<td>
    <a ng-href="/dossiers/{{dossier.id}}">@{{dossier.license_plate}}</a>
</td>
```

```
<a ng-href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref